# Is language of binary representations regular?

Tags: regular-language

> Let $bin(n)$ denote binary representation of an integer $n$. Let $L=\left\{bin(n^2):n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$. Is $L$ a regular language?

Comment: What is a "regular language"?

Comment: @moray95 [Regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $p$ is any polynomial, then $\{ \operatorname{bin}(p(n)) : n\in\Bbb N \}$ is regular if and only if $p$ is constant or first degree.

It is easy to prove that this case, where $p$ is the second-degree polynomial $n^2$, is irregular, using the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem).

Comment: It is very interesting what you say is in general. I didn't know that. Is it very hard to prove? I believe that in this particular case pumping lemma should be efficient (and that is only one way, I know, to prove such things) but completely don't know how to start. I was thinking maybe consider only particular subset of $L$ such as $10^{N-1}10^{N+1}1$ but this led me to nowhere.

Comment: Proving that a subset of $L$ is irregular won't help, because there are many regular languages that contain irregular subsets.

Comment: You're right, thanks! But given subset of $L$ (let's call it $L'$) is equal to $10^*10^*1 \cap L$ so if $L$ is regular then $L'$ too. Then if I prove $L'$ not regular then $L$ not regular. Can this argument work?

Comment: $L'$ is not equal to $10^*10^*1\cap L$, which contains `110001`$ = 7^2$ and `100100001`$= 17^2$.

Comment: Right, thank you. I write stupid things..

Comment: That's not stupid. It doesn't work, but it was worth considering. I think there are a lot of ways to solve this problem.